# How to document return type of function taking generic argument as the type of that argument

Tags: python, generics, types, pylance

Suppose I have a function taking a generic argument, `x: Type[_T]`, where `_T = TypeVar("_T", bound=MyClassBase)`, and `MyClassBase` has an attribute `my_attr`. I would like to document the return type of this function as being the type of `my_attr` for the given class.

I have tried the following code, running Python 3.8 in VSCode with pylance, but it does not pass type checking:

```py
class MyClassBase:
    my_attr: Any

class MyClassStr(MyClassBase):
    my_attr: str = "hi"

class MyClassInt(MyClassBase):
    my_attr: int = 1

_T = TypeVar("_T", bound=MyClassBase)
def test(x: Type[_T]) -> _T.my_attr: # Pylance: Cannot access member "my_attr" for type "TypeVar". Member "my_attr" is unknown
    return x.my_attr

a = test(MyClassStr) # Desired type of `a` should be `str`
```

Is there another way to do this? Or is it just not possible?